# who to follow in twitter or People you may know in facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, twitter

I want to implement a functionality similar to "Who to follow" in twitter or "People you may know" in facebook. Where suggestions are provided, and if you want to add in your network just click follow or add friend link.

while we click follow (or add friend in FB), that particular suggestion disappears from the suggestion list, and a new suggestion is available. HOW to achieve this functionality.

Also if we click on close button (right top corner), that particular suggestion goes away, and a new suggestion is available. HOW to achieve this functionality too.

What tools, techniques i should use?

I am not looking how to fetch the suggestion(s), i want how to implement the disappear and new suggestion fetch functionality.

Comment: Have you thought about how to actually achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon click of accept or close get a new suggestion and add an element for it:

```
var getNext = function() {
    $.getJSON("suggestion.php", function(data) {
        $("#suggestions").append($("span").hide().text(data.name)).fadeIn();
    });
};
$(".suggestion .accept, .suggestion .close").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".suggestion").fadeOut();
    getNext();
})
```

However my example doesn't bother adding close and accept buttons to the new suggestions.